# How to split the column?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe (JSON file) with many columns (`contributors`, `country name`, `prices` ...)
The column `Prices` has a list of values.

Example for one country (one row in a table):

```
{'contributors': '200',
'name': 'Andorra',
'prices': [{'min price': '23.0',
'avg price': '25.5',
'max price': '32.5',
'item name': 'meal'},
{'min price': '17.0',
'avg price': '20.5',
'max price': '24.5',
'item name': 'drinks'}, ....] }
```

I want to split a column with prices, with `item_names` as a column names, and average prices as values in that column.

It should look like this:

```
{'contributors': '200',
'name': 'Andorra',
'meal': '25.5',
'drinks': '20.5',
 .... }
```

There are 55 items for prices. So the table should have 55 columns for prices instead of one.

Comment: Can you please remove the image and add as text?

Comment: I added the text, hope everything is clear now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explode the prices array, and then do a group by and pivot based on the relevant struct values:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = (df.selectExpr('name', 'explode(prices) prices')
         .groupBy('name')
         .pivot('prices.item_name')
         .agg(F.first('prices.average_price'))
      )
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems like it works. But when I created a temporary view, and selected to show only country name and prices for apples, it looks like this ->                                      
  name: Chad, Apples (1kg), Markets: Apples (1kg), Markets

Comment: I mean it doesn't show the prices, it duplicates the name of the column